# How to pass a custom error message to a jasmine matcher?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

In all the testing frameworks I have used, there is an optional parameter to specify you own custom error message.

This can be very useful, and I can't find a way to do this out of the box with jasmine.

I've had 3 other developers ask me about this exact functionality, and when it comes to jasmine I don't know what to tell them.

Is it possible to specify your own custom error message on each assertion ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you take a look at the jasmine source code you will see that there is no way to set the message from outside a matcher. For example the `toBeNaN` matcher.

```
/**
 * Matcher that compares the actual to NaN.
 */
jasmine.Matchers.prototype.toBeNaN = function() {
  this.message = function() {
      return [ "Expected " + jasmine.pp(this.actual) + " to be NaN." ];
  };

  return (this.actual !== this.actual);
};
```

As you can see the messages is hard coded into the matcher and will be set when you call the matcher. The only way I can think of to have your own messages is to write your matcher like described [here](http://uxebu.com/blog/2013/01/08/make-tests-read-like-a-book/)

Comment: If you want add more details to jasmine hardcoded message - all matchers have optional parameter for that - check @Xotabu4 answer for more detials

Answer (score 22):

**Update 2022;** Use `.withContext(...)` method instead of below (as optional parameter is deprecated).

---

Jasmine already supports optional parameter in all matchers (toBe, toContain, and others), so you can use:

```
expect(true).toBe(false, 'True should be false').
```

Then in output it will look like this:

```
Message:
    Expected true to be false, 'True should be false'.
```

Link to commit (this is not described in documentation):
https://github.com/ronanamsterdam/DefinitelyTyped/commit/ff104ed7cc13a3eb2e89f46242c4dbdbbe66665e

Comment: It doesn't work with `toEqual` in Jasmine 3.6.3 for some reason

Comment: @Finesse not just that, all optional parameters are deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Chain-call [withContext()](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers.html#withContext) right after `expect()`. Example:

```js
expect(myValue)
  .withContext("This message will be printed when the expectation doesn't match")
  .toEqual({foo: 'bar'});
```

Answer (score 5):

[This issue](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/641) is tracking interest in implementing custom error messages using a `.because()` mechanism.

In the meantime, [avrelian](https://github.com/avrelian) has created a nice library which implements custom error messages using a `since()` mechanism – [`jasmine-custom-message`](https://github.com/avrelian/jasmine-custom-message).

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it can be done.**

You may define a custom matcher in global scope, overriding the error message in jasmine as below:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toReport: function () {
            return {
                compare: function (actual, expected, msg) {
                    var result = {pass: actual == expected};
                    result.message = msg;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!